# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, range, configobj

I'm trying to make my app run files with Unicode characters, but for this, you must decode before them. For this I am using ConfigObj.py. But when I run the app, get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "GCW_Player.py", line 757, in <module>
     epMEDIA ()
   File "GCW_Player.py", line 89, in __ init__
     self.keyhandler (event.key)
   File "GCW_Player.py", line 133, in keyhandler
     if key == K_RIGHT: self.k_goto ()
   File "GCW_Player.py", line 211, in k_goto
     self.go_to ()
   File "GCW_Player.py", line 649, in go_to
     self.list.generate (self.sec_ftypes)
   File "/data/epm_core.py", line 114, in generate
     inp = os.listdir (self.path)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

Below, let the corresponding part file in the app:

```
    def generate(self, filetypes):
        self.data = []
        inp = os.listdir(self.path)
        inp.sort()
        for line in inp:
            file = File(os.path.join(self.path, line), filetypes)
            if file.type != None:
                self.data.append(file)
```

Can anyone help me? I do not know what to do in this case. I've never experienced this situation. Thank you.

Comment: can you check if self.path is really a string.

Comment: `self.path` is most likely a tuple.

Comment: Don't name Python files with spaces in them. They'll be a horrible pain to use; you can't import them (or at least not without extensive, ugly workarounds), and you have to quote them or backslash-escape the spaces at the command line.

Comment: yes, it is. `self.path` will take the path of the archives.

Comment: Ok, now tell us exactly what it is that `self.path` contains here

Comment: He will keep the full path to the files that the app uses. Before I try to use ConfigObj, all files WITHOUT special characters functioned normally.

Comment: I'll leave a link to the full file, if anyone wants to help, it becomes easier to understand the problem: [epm_core.py](http://pastebin.com/QP9GTwEB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `self.path` contains multiple paths, maybe you need:

```
def generate(self, filetypes):
    self.data = []

    for folder in self.path:
        inp = os.listdir(folder)
        inp.sort()
        for line in inp:
            file = File(os.path.join(folder, line), filetypes)
            if file.type != None:
                self.data.append(file)
```

Comment: Thank you, Antti Haapala, but now I get this error:


`File "data/epm_core.py", line 116, in generate`
`inp = os.listdir(folder)`
`TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ConfigObj found`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just a long time I've solved this issue, with simple modifying. Just I use u"" string in all parts that can have a unicode caracter. Using encode.utf8().decode.utf8() is more difficult, so just use u"" strings in the correct moments.